# Is there a way to remove some webpage headers in apache or nginX to reducae latency?

Tags: performance, apache, web, header, nginx

When a page is requested there would be parameters as below:

```
Pragma  
Cache-Control  
Content-Type  
Date   
Content-length
```

Is there a way to remove `Date` for example? Or remove most of them (except Pargam and some caching mechanisms) for image files? Could we get performance gain here? Should we do it on web server layer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Date` header is [required by HTTP/1.1](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.18). `Content-Type` and `Content-length` are also valuable and small to have, and you already mentioned that cache headers were important to you. So, I think you are looking in the wrong place for optimization.

What you can do is make sure that images served from a domain separate from the application to make sure the clients aren't sending cookie headers when they request static images. Using a CDN for serving static content is also recommended.

Comment: I've already put `static server for serving images` into my real consideration. thanks. ;)